# Error in R: DGEList(counts, group) : 'lib.size' must be numeric

Tags: r, syntax-error

Our professor gives us generic example code that we must modify to fit our personal dataset. I'm using GSE117588 from the GEO database if that's helpful at all. Here is the line of code giving me trouble:

```
group <- c(rep("G1",3), rep("G2",3))
counts <- data1
cds <- DGEList( counts , group)
names(cds)

head(cds$counts) # original count matrix
cds$samples # contains a summary of your samples
sum(cds$all.zeros) # How many genes have 0 counts across all samples 

cds <- calcNormFactors(cds, method="upperquartile")
cds$samples
```

In response to `cds <- DGEList(counts, group)` it returns error message `'lib.size' must be numeric`. I have downloaded `edgeR` and am not sure what to input to debug. I apologize in advance if this is a simple question, I am very new to coding!

Comment: I saw on a bioinformatics forum, this can be resolved with adding row.names=1 when inputting file.choose() however upon changing that, I still receive the error message and R appears to still have difficulties with the geneID's

Comment: cds <- DGEList( counts=counts , group=group)  
instead of cds <- DGEList( counts , group)  
should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem earlier, and realised that when you run calcNormFactors before DGEList, make sure you run it on the count table of the object (in your case counts), then it should be solved.

Working Example:

```
library(SummarizedExperiment)

#simulate data1 
set.seed(123) 
data1 = data.frame(G1A = rnorm(10,3,2), G1B = rnorm(10,4,2), G1C = rnorm(10,3,2), G2A = rnorm(10,2,2), G2B = rnorm(10,3,2),G2C = rnorm(10,3,3))
data1 = data1+10 #to make whole df positive

group <- c(rep("G1",3), rep("G2",3))

nF = calcNormFactors(data1) 
dge0 = DGEList(counts = data1, group = group, norm.factors = nF)
```

Alternatively, if you wish to create the object and then calculate normFactors

```
dge0 = DGEList(counts = data1, group = group)
nF = calcNormFactors(dge0$counts)

# slot the normFactors back into dge0 object
dge0$samples[,"norm.factors"] <- nF
```